# Позиционирование элемента в верстке

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Не могу разобраться в верстке логотипа в шапке сайта.

При изменении масштаба страницы логотип плывет относительно левого блока слайдера. Пробовал использовать media query но они работают только под определенные разрешения.

http://goo.gl/elOK7Z

Answer (score 2):

Медиа-запросы в [media.css](http://opo.moscow/css/media.css) меняют `margin-left` для логотипа и `padding-left` для фона всей шапки. Причём, нижние и верхние условия в этих медиа-запросах расставлены сумбурно:

```
@media (max-width: 1600px){
    .header-bg2 img{
        margin-left: 122px;
    }
} 
@media (max-width: 1280px){
    .header-bg2 img{
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .header-bg2 {
        padding-left: 0px;  
    }
    .header-bg {
        padding-left: 0px;  
    }
} 
    @media (max-width: 1440px){
    .header-bg2 img{
        margin-left: 50px;
    }
} 
@media (max-width: 768px){
    .header-bg2 img{
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1900px){
    .header-bg2 img{
        margin-left: 282px;
    }
} 
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .header-bg2 img{
        margin-left: 0px;
        width: 80%;
    }
}
```

В результате при ширине экрана 1057 пикселей логотип попадает под заголовок сайта, а как исправлять - непонятно.

[image: ошибка вёрстки]

Поскольку страница использует Бутстрап, а Бутстрап перешёл на `Mobile first`, рекомендую в качестве образца их собственную [структуру медиа-запросов](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries):

- либо медиа-запросы используют `min-width` и расположены в порядке возрастания нижней границы
- либо используют `min-width` и `max-width` одновременно (кроме медиа-запросов для самого узкого и самого широкого экранов)
- `max-width` подойдёт медиа-запросу для самого узкого экрана

Например:

```
@media (max-width: 1280px){
  .header-bg {
    padding-left: 0px;  
  }
  .header-bg2 {
    padding-left: 0px;  
  }
  .header-bg2 img{
    margin-left: 0;
  }
} 
@media (min-width: 1281px){
  .header-bg2 img{
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
} 
@media (min-width: 1441px){
  .header-bg2 img{
    margin-left: 122px;
  }
} 
@media (min-width: 1601px){
  .header-bg2 img{
    margin-left: 282px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Он плывет, потому что им управляет сетка Bootstrap. При изменении масштаба, перестраивается сетка и блок "плавает".